# Learn sentence embeddings from a sequence of token embeddings

Tags: classification, word-embeddings, embeddings, transformers

I want to build a sentence classifier that takes the sentence as a sequence of token embeddings. I'm specifically interested in the methodology for learning the sentence embedding from the sequence of token embeddings as part of a classification model.

[image: Model diagram]

I've looked at various ways to do this:

**Mean and max pool the token embeddings**

This isn't sufficient as I want the model to learn the embeddings during training. I am using BERT token embeddings and averaging them doesn't fully utilise their power.

**Transformer layer/stack**

I've tried using a transformer encoder and taking the first token's embedding. I believe this approach would work well but unfortunately it makes the model too large (number of trainable parameters). It also seems like there is a lot of wasted computation as the output for most of the tokens is discarded.

**LSTM**

I haven't yet tried this approach, but I plan to try this next.

---

My BERT model was only trained with the Masked Language Modelling objective, so I don't think taking the `[CLS]` token's embedding will perform well.

- Are there other techniques I should be looking at?
- What do you think of the LSTM approach?
- Is there a paper I can refer to for this (learning sentence embedding from a series of token embeddings, ideally as part of a classification stack)?

Many thanks for your help.